# Get historical data of the S&P500?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for data of the S&P 500; The data should have the following properties:

1. It should contain all daily returns of the past 6 or 8 years for all stocks included in the S&P500 - so not just the daily returns of the S&P500 itself;
2. It should have a format I can process in Matlab (my favourite) or R

Any idea where to get it for free?

Comment: Check out https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/sp500-components-at-specific-date and the linked resources. Finding the components of the S&P500 at a given time is probably harder than finding data for those components.